# What would be the best navigation label for a website section containing forms, documents and videos?

Tags: user-behavior, information-architecture, labels

**I'm having trouble coming up with labels for a navigation category and a page. Looking for input!** The project i'm working on is a website redesign for a business's employee benefit plan. The site will be structured as follows:

- Home
- About
- Insurance
- Pension
- **Unnamed Category**
  - **Unnamed Page**
  - Life Events

- The **'Unnamed Category'** needs to describe the two pages below.
- The **'Unnamed Page'** will be a gallery view that displays a very large database of forms that need to be filled out to apply to benefits, as well as testimonial videos, webinars, and articles/documents about benefits. I thought about labeling this page 'Documents & Videos' but wasn't sure if this was descriptive enough. It is too broad & does not indicate to the user that this is where they can find important forms. I don't want the label to get too long either - Documents, Forms, Videos & Webinars starts to get clunky.
- The **'Life Events'** page will contain a section of content for each life event and links to forms/info required at the time of that event. (Life events include marriage, maternity leave, sick leave, retirement, etc.)

*NOTE: There are two user groups on the site - the business's administration that may need to find files to give to employees, and current employees of the business.*

**What would you label the Unnamed Category?

What would you label the Unnamed Page?**

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided, straightforward suggestion would be:  
**Unnamed Category** - Benefits 
*The section contains all the Documents, webinars, videos etc, which as a whole, gives the gist of Benefits the business is providing to the user.*  

**Unnamed Page** - View Benefits 
*The page gives information about various benefits and the forms to apply to those benefits. The page should provide overall idea what is the page about, what the user is suppose to do on that page.*

Comment: Hey Pooja, thank you for the response! Benefits is redundant and also too vague. Employees receive Insurance and a Pension Plan. Those are their benefits, so those two sections will contain all of the general information about the employee benefits. The unnamed pages/sections will be more of an asset manager/

Comment: @alecianicole Okay. Do provide the whole scenario of the navigation bar, so that it doesn't create any misunderstanding. Full context to the problem leads to more accurate answer. Anyways, happy to help next time.